# Whats is Missing?

Tags: java, sql

Please tell me my mistake in this Query

```
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
                 "CREATE TABLE "
                         + TABLE_NAME + 
                         "("+ USERID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                         + USER_NAME +"VARCHAR(255),"
                         + USER_PASSWORD + "TEXT,"
                         +USER_EMAIL+ "TEXT"+")";
```

Comment: tell us what error is giving ..

Comment: Well, first you are not using a parameterized query, that may be a security problem.

Comment: You need spaces `column_name data_type(size)`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 4):

At least, you need to have a space before INTEGER, VARCHAR(255), and TEXT

If you print your CREATE_TABLE string, I'm sure you'll be able to troubleshoot your query effectively.

Comment: Sorry dear i am try but its not working